# How to get gcc to work on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, gcc

I am trying to get gcc to work on OS X.

However my Mac OS X gcc compiler keeps complaining about not being able to find definitions for `std` classes like `vector` and ``string`.

I am suspecting if gcc on OS X actually support standard C++ library, and if so, how to set it up so that these compilation errors would go away...

This is my compiler version:

```
$ gcc -v 

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0 Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Did you include the appropriate header files? What is a minimal code snippet that has one of those errors (and what is the error, specifically)?

Comment: I think you want to use the `g++` command, not `gcc`.

Comment: Note you are actually using Apple's version of LLVM/Clang - not GCC even though you call `gcc`. On Mac OS, things are sometimes a bit different. If you really want to use GCC, you need [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) or something similar. That said, @AlexanderO'Mara might have solved your problem already - LLVM/Clang are quite good and you might not even need GCC.

Comment: I understood that gcc on OS X actually uses llvm/clang, at least the version command provided the info. 

Here is some simple code that won't compile:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
        return -1;

    string ver1 = argv[1];
    string ver2 = argv[2];
...
}

stringtest.cpp:17:5: error: unknown type name 'string'
    string ver1 = argv[1];
    ^
stringtest.cpp:18:5: error: unknown type name 'string'
    string ver2 = argv[2];

Comment: and the above error happens when using g++

Comment: You need to include `string`, not `string.h`. And you need to use `std::string` in the code. Get a beginner's book on C++ to help getting started on the basics.

Comment: @Daniel Frey yes including <string> instead of <string.h> solved the issue. Thanks for that. It turned out that g++ on OS X is also realized by llvm/clang. And I did not need to include std in my code to get it to work. This is really annoying with LLVM: exactly what works and what does not with LLVM for standard C++. std::stoi did not work either and I had to use std::atoi, whatever that is...